# How can you move objects in Viva Piñata?

Tags: viva-pinata

Once placed, is it possible to move objects in Viva Piñata, and if so, how can you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no,
but there is a trick:
If you have Xbox live (at least silver) you can sent already placed buildings via post to your self and so replace them.